# Cakephp Email input validation exception

Tags: validation, email, cakephp

I have validation for the email input in my form but I would also like to create an exception for a string: "Not given" as some contact information do not have an email address. I know I can remove the email validation to do this but I want that validation there for new contacts. Those that do not have email addresses are some of the old contacts. So I would need an exception in order for me to add those contacts into this new system.

My current email validation in the model is as follows:

```
'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'uniqueEmail' => array(
            'rule'=>'isUnique',
            'message' => 'This email has already been added'
        ),
    )
```

How do I implement this exception and where?

Any help would be great. Thanks!!

Comment: 1. The old contacts (without an email) are already in the database ?
2. What differentiates between a contact that needs email to be allowed empty and what does not ?

Comment: @omar.php
Those contacts are not already in the database. They are from paper records and need to be added into the database. 

Those contacts that needs email to be allowed empty are existing contacts. There are hundreds of them and I dont think it's wise to call all of them up asking for their email address. But any new contacts from then on will be required to provide an email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncomment that `'allowEmpty' => false` line and change it to `true`, this will permit the email filled to be submitted as an empty string.

Comment: is there another way to create an exception as I do not want a user to be submitting the form without putting an email address. allowing empty will allow them to skip the email field.

Comment: You could use a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules), or you could also remove the email validation rule for an old user. I suggest you read the page I linked to, validation rules are very flexible in CakePHP 2.2